# In Jenkins does perforce plugin supports CL code download?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

Does Jenkins Perforce plugin supports particular Change List(CL) based source code download?

Comment: Not an answer but a place to start reading: In the Jenkins JIRA issues database, there is a request that explains the issue and ways to do what you're asking. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4603